# how to deploy log4j only use notepad 

Tags: java, log4j

i am a Java beginner and i want to use log4j , but i hate eclipse. I use `programmer's notepad` to write python and javascript. So how to use log4j if I use `programmer's notepad`

what can i do ,

```
log4j_demo
     --HelloLog4j.java
     --lib
          ---log4j-1.2.8.jar
          ---log4j.properties
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried Netbeans? I prefer Eclipse myself, but trust me, you _do_ want to use an IDE if you want to do anything with Java. If you feel an IDE is overkill for your project, you chose the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: IntelliJ is another IDE option.  Honestly I prefer Eclipse as well, I love Eclipse.

Comment: I get it!  That "example" is actually supposed to depict your **directory** structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of the tool you are using but all you need to do is to make sure log4j jar and your log4j.properties is in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the log4j page: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html. They have no hard bound dependency on using eclipse. Any text editor will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the short answer is that Programmer's Notepad doesn't have much support for Java, but you can do it if you are prepared to "wing it".  [This forum thread](http://pnotepad.org/forums/topic/112) may be helpful.

And of course, the other approach is to use Programmer's Notepad as *just* an editor, and run `javac` or `ant` from the command line to do your builds, etc.

Either way, to use log4j you simply need to make sure that the relevant JAR file is on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any text editor to write Java. Unlike Python and Javascript you must compile Java code before it can be executed. `javac` (Java Compiler) is included in the Java Development Kit.

Oracle has a [short tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html) on how to compile and run Java.